# Coldfusion Excel Formatting Error

Tags: excel, coldfusion, apache-poi

I can't seem to do any formatting in Coldfusion, trying to do anything at all means its throws this error

```
NoSuchMethodError : org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.getCharSet()B
```

This is the problem area of the code, the problem is in the last couple of lines, everything else works fine.

```
<cfscript> 
            sheet = SpreadsheetNew("JEreport", "yes"); 
            SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"JE Report - Charge for Moves",1,1);
            SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"JE Report Charge for Moves for the Period From: " & toString(local.formatStartDate) & " To: " & toString(local.formatEndDate),3,1);
            SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"Report Date: " & toString(local.formatNow),4,1);
            SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"Created by: " & local.employee.empl_firstname & " " & local.employee.empl_lastname & " (" & session.user.getAlias() & ")",5,1);
            SpreadsheetAddRow(sheet,"Move ID,Move Type,Number of Movees (people),Number of Movees (items),Movees (people),Move Requested Date,Move Completed Date,Funding Category,Funding Type,Funding Source",7,1);

            for(i = 1; i <= local.numOfProjects; i++){
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].projectId,i+8,1);
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].move_type,i+8,2);
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].num_movers,i+8,3);
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].num_items,i+8,4);
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].movers,i+8,5);
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"Not Currently Available",i+8,6);
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].move_start_date,i+8,7);
                if(local.arrayProjects[i].move_type == "group"){
                    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].move_funding_cat,i+8,8);
                }else{
                    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"N/A",i+8,8);
                }
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].move_funding_type,i+8,9);
                SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,local.arrayProjects[i].move_funding_source,i+8,10);
            }
            format1=structnew();
            format1.bold="true"; 
            theFile=GetDirectoryFromPath(arguments.tempDir) & "jeTemp.xlsx"; 
            format1.alignment="center"; 
            SpreadsheetFormatColumn(sheet,format1,5);
        </cfscript>
```

I'm not sure what to do. I'm obviously missing something but what? I'm using Coldfusion 10 so shouldn't I have all I need to do some Spreadsheet formatting already?

Comment: Can you post all of the code so we can see everything?

Comment: Does it run successfully without, "SpreadsheetFormatColumn(sheet,format1,5);"?

Comment: What POI jars do you have installed in ColdFusion? And do you perhaps have a mis-matched set?

Comment: Yes it runs fine without that line. As for the POI jars, Im not sure. Will get back on that one

Answer (score 0):

as per the documents, SpreadsheetFormatColumn takes 4 arguments (spreadsheetObj, format, row, column). I just tried it on my dev box and with 3 parameters it threw error. Try providing row as well as col parameter and it should work.

Comment: Spreadsheet format column takes 3 arguments. Why would a function that formats a column need a row number as an argument? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6806.html

Comment: sorry, I mixed it up with SpreadsheetFormatCell. SpreadsheetFormatColumn works for me. Looking at your error, is it possible that format1.bold="true"; could be causing trouble with POI jar?